# MaterializeCSS side nav not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I am having the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439042/materialize-css-side-nav-not-working) post, but the answer that was given hasn't worked for me. When I try using the MaterializeCSS mobile hamburger menu, it only works on the first time that it is pressed and afterwards just adds a hastag to the end of the URL and doesn't actually open the side navbar at all.

My HTML:

```
<nav class="white">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a id="logo-container" href="/" class="brand-logo center">JCSDevelopment</a>
        <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="mobile-demo" class="side-nav">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And my JS:

```
$(window).scroll( function(){

    $('.hideme').each( function(i){
        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
            console.log('reveal image');
        };
    });
});

(function($){
    $(function(){
        $('.parallax').parallax();
        $('.button-collapse').sideNav();
    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

I have put the solution into my code, I have also tried putting the rest of my JS into the `.ready()` function and placed the `.sideNav()` function last but that didn't work either.

Comment: Look at your console, are there errors?

Comment: Yeah I just looked and I have `Deferred long-running timer task(s) to improve scrolling smoothness. See crbug.com/574343.` coming up when I try it.

Comment: Looking online it seems to be a chrome thing, it doesn't work in firefox either but that message doesn't come up there. Very confused!

Comment: I would just start from the beginning and re-trace your steps. Get rid of all your other JS and try to make the nav work by itself. It looks like you can also do it programmatically, maybe try that. From their docs: 
  `$('.button-collapse').sideNav('show');` and `$('.button-collapse').sideNav('hide');`

Comment: Also, are you adding in all the JS libraries you need? In the right order? jQuery first?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your `$(window).scroll` handler is interfering with the parallax plugin, but it's hard to tell without your full markup. Have you tried using the [materializecss scrollfire plugin](http://materializecss.com/scrollfire.html) instead?

[This codepen](http://codepen.io/appworkshop/pen/rLMrpL) shows the hamburger working nicely together with parallax.

[This codepen](http://codepen.io/appworkshop/pen/EygpdX) is the same as the previous one, but it also demonstrates using the scrollfire plugin to change an image opacity.